# How to change application id uri?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Why can I sometimes modify the Failed to update Application ID URI, but at other times I can't?

**Failed to update Application ID URI:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your application supported account types to single tenant.